# Exporting currency and percentage vales from R to Excel using openxlsx- Excel shows "number stored as text" error

Tags: r, excel, export-to-excel

I am exporting for currency (e.g. $ 20) and percentage (e.g. 20%) from R to Excel using openxlsx package. Even though the numbers appear well formatted in R (though as character), in excel there is the error message "Number stored as text" with a small green triangle on the upper left side of the cells where this happen.

Is there any way to fix it? It is easy to fix manually for each cell or table, but I am creating a file with many tabs and a few tables on each tab. Is there any way to fix this for the whole workbook right from R? Any suggestions on ways to go about this?

Comment: Why not make your columns numeric in R? This sounds like expected behaviour to me. If the columns are character in R they ought to be character in Excel. Use `as.numeric`

Comment: Thank you! You were right; I removed the "$" I had included the numeric columns that had turned them into character. So, they became numeric again. I still needed to turn them into currencies in Excel, so I used the numfmt option in the createStyle function in openxlsx.